# Changed TableViewCell with XMSegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segment

I want to changed tableviewcell's data with XMSegmentedControl(https://github.com/xaviermerino/XMSegmentedControl),
and I using switch in the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

,but it's always print

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**,and say *segmentedControl1 is nil.
```

---

```
let tin = ["1","2","3","4"]
let how = ["one","two","three","four"]
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl1: XMSegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let segmentedControl3 = XMSegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44), segmentTitle: ["Hello", "World", "Three"], selectedItemHighlightStyle: XMSelectedItemHighlightStyle.topEdge)
    segmentedControl3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 22/255, green: 150/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)
    segmentedControl3.highlightColor = UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 180/255, blue: 145/255, alpha: 1)
    segmentedControl3.tint = UIColor.white
    segmentedControl3.highlightTint = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl3)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    switch(segmentedControl1.selectedSegment)
    {
    case 0 :
        returnValue = tin.count
    case 1 :
        returnValue = how.count
    default :
        break
    }
    return returnValue
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    switch(segmentedControl1.selectedSegment)
    {
    case 0 :
        cell.textLabel?.text = tin[indexPath.row]
    case 1 :
        cell.textLabel?.text = how[indexPath.row]
    default :
        break
    }
    return cell
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace your `viewDidLoad()` by my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     segmentedControl1 = XMSegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44), segmentTitle: ["Hello", "World", "Three"], selectedItemHighlightStyle: XMSelectedItemHighlightStyle.topEdge)
    segmentedControl1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 22/255, green: 150/255, blue: 122/255, alpha: 1)
    segmentedControl1.highlightColor = UIColor(red: 25/255, green: 180/255, blue: 145/255, alpha: 1)
    segmentedControl1.tint = UIColor.white
    segmentedControl1.highlightTint = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl1)
}
```

put into valuechenged method of segmentControl

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
             self.ttblView.reloadData()
            }
```

You have applied wrong segmentControl . You put value in segmentedControl3 so segmentedControl1 gives nil .